# "command not found" ошибка git bash при попытке коммита и прохождения тестов на Windows

Tags: javascript, git, git-commit

У меня есть несколько прекоммитных тестов. При попытке коммита возникает эта ошибка. Я пыталась прописать путь ("C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe") в переменных среды в настройках системы Windows и также создала файл .bashrc в папке пользователя и прописала путь там. Но ничего из этого не помогло, есть ли какие-то способы решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/720

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться